# removing some elements from a vector by position

Tags: c++, vector

what is the fastest way to remove a set of non-contiguous elements (which I have their positions) from a vector ? Or getting a new vector without these elements.

For example I have vector v1 = <5, 9, 6, 7, 12, 0, 3>. And I have a vector of positions that I want to eliminate vector rem = <0, 3, 4, 6> or a vector containing true/false depending on whether or not the element should be eliminated or not vector rem = . Then the new vector would be vector v2 = <9, 6, 0>.

Comment: should you keep the order of the elements in the original vector?

Comment: The obvious solution would be to iterate the vector of indices you want to remove, and then call `erase(iterator)` on v1.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev not necessarily we can get for example V2=<0,9,6>, but it should not be random ... if I apply again the same function to v1 it should return the elements in v2 in the same order ..

Comment: Is space a concern?  E.g. is it acceptable to have two copies of your vector in the worst case?

Comment: @JaredC I don't care about space, the time is more important for me.

Answer (score 2):

If order of the elements in the original vector does not matter I would suggest you iterate over the indices you want to remove in increasing order(that is important) and for each element to swap it with the last element in the vector and than call `pop_back`.

You will also have to perform checks to see if the last element of the vector is to be removed before performing the swap. While the index of the last element is also among the ones to be removed `pop_back` and **then** do the swap and `pop_back`.

EDIT: just to clarify - as you have the indices of the elements to be removed already sorted, you may check if the last element is to be removed by simply checking the last value **you have not yet removed** in the array of indices. Use an helper integer index to keep track of which that index is, initialize it to the size of the array of indices to remove minus one and decrement it by one each time the last element is to be removed.

Comment: @shn I can but believe it is better if you come up with the code on your own. It is a good exercise on handling vectors. I would give you guidance if you get stuck on a particular part of the implementation, but don't want to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: @JaredC it is constant with respect to additional space and linear with respect to the indices we need to remove(assuming they are already sorted).

Comment: +1 nice solution - definitely faster than mine.  Though I wonder based on comments - did @shn need both vectors afterwards?

Comment: @RobI from his question, I thought he need either of the options, whichever performs faster.

Comment: OK, it's clear after rereading.  Though I can't quite see how this solution would work if removing the last element, say removing "b" and "c" from ["a", "b", "c"].

Comment: I mentioned in my last sentence special care should be taken to see if you are removing the last element. Remember indices are sorted so you can see if the greatest left to be removed equals the size of the vector minus one on **each** step

Comment: So when removing "b", you'd see that "c" also needs removal, pop "c", swap "b" with itself, and pop "b".  But then I guess you also have to pop the last index element when this happens?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23316/discussion-between-ivaylo-strandjev-and-rob-i)

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the vectors together, kind of like a merge algorithm.  Something like this:

```
int index1=0, index2=0;

while (index1 < v1.size()) {
    if ( index2 < rem.size() && index1 == rem[index2] ) {
        index2++; // skip this one
    }
    else {
        v2.push_back(v1[index1]); // keep this one
    }

    index1++;
}
```

Using iterators would be cleaner, and note that the `rem` vector must be sorted.

Edit: corrected by using a 3rd variable name for the indices vector.

Answer (score 0):

By fastest I'm assuming with the shortest amount of code and also a bit of optimization:

```
size_t i = 0;
size_t end = v1.size();
vector<int> vresult;

vresult.reserve(v1.size() - rem.size()); // avoid reallocations

size_t remIt = 0;
for ( ; i != end; ++i )
{
  if ( i != rem[remIt] )
    vresult.push_back(v1[i]); // push our element into the new vector
  else
    remIt++;
}
```

Might not compile, code above is written purely for its algorithm.